# Zend db table - save() not saving

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I cannot update an entry in my table. The code I am using is below:

```
class Model_Notification extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = "notifications";
    public function encrypt($id,$key)
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->where('id = ?', $id);
        $row = $this->fetchRow($select);

        if( $row )
        {
            $row->key = $key;
            $row->save();
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

At first, I thought it might be the column name "key", so I changed it to "passkey" but no success. I am getting true returned to me every time!

I can still add/delete to the table, but I canon understand why this update `save()` does not work!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more optimised way

```
$table = new Table();
$data = array(
    "field1" => "value1",
    "field2" => "value2"
);
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto("id = ?",$id);


$table->update($data, $where);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$data = array(
    "field1" => "value1",
    "field2" => "value2"
);
$where = "id = " . $id;

$table = new Table();
$table->update($data, $where);
```